# Single database with multiple DBContext "Error: unable to model the end of the foreign key on principal table table_name

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, dbcontext, ef-core-2.2

I have one database with multiple schemas and I want to create separate   DBContext for each schema. I am using ef core for model creation. In the first schema, I have a table name Company with Primary Key CompanyID and in the second schema, I have a table name User with Foreign key of CompanyID. When I create a model of the second schema it shows below error at package manager console:

"For foreign key User_CompanyID_fkey on table cs.User, unable to model the end of the foreign key on the principal table app.Company. This is usually because the principal table was not included in the selection set."

How I could achieve this, or should I use single DBContext?

Comment: No, you could not refernce the table fk which is in different dbcontext. You need to use them in the same dbcontext.